# Prove that if $\bigtriangledown \times F=0,$ then $\exists u$ such that $F= \bigtriangledown u$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

If $\bigtriangledown \times  F=0,$ then $\exists $ a function $u$ such that $F= \bigtriangledown u$

The converse is straightforward to prove, but this statement is giving a hard time.

Any hints/tips/tricks?

Thank youuu!

Comment: It's a bit delicate. Whether or not it's true depends on the domain $\Omega$ of $F$. If it's simply connected you can proceed by fixing some point $x_0\in\Omega$ and defining $u(x)$ as line integral along any curve (say, smooth) connecting $x_0$ and $x$ (use Stokes' theorem to show $u$ is well-defined this way).

Comment: @MarcinŁoś: But then, strictly speaking, we need to know that any piecewise-smooth closed curve in $\Bbb R^3$ bounds an *orientable* surface.

Comment: @TedShifrin Hmm... right, details of using Stokes here may be a bit hairy. Perhaps there's some easier way to show path independence?

Comment: @MarcinŁoś: One can do this, indeed, with Stokes's Theorem, by proving that $\int_{S^1} f^*\omega=\int_{S^1} g^*\omega$ whenever $f,g\colon S^1\to\Omega$ are homotopic maps and $\omega$ is a closed 1-form on $\Omega$ (this is the curl$=0$ condition).